# Does Eclipse IDE support angularjs 2

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, typescript

I have the AngularJS 1.1.0 plugin installed. Now, I want to start using 
AngularJS 2.0, so I need the plugin for Eclipse IDE. But, I didn't find it in Eclipse Market. Even for TypeScript, the maximum plugin version that I found for Eclipse was 1.0.0, however AngularJS 2.0 need at least TypeScript 1.5 .

So, does Eclipse support AngularJS 2.0 ?

Comment: I have planned to work for Angular2 Eclipse https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse but before starting it I must finish TypeScript support https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java

Comment: nice,  so I am waitting  :)

Answer (score 0):

> Even for TypeScript, the maximum plugin version that I found for Eclipse was 1.0.0

This is the defacto TypeScript IDE for eclipse : https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript